# DO i need to localize the link url for opening an app in the appstore?I

Tags: app-store, openurl

I have to open my apps link in the app store in case the version number of the app they are using is not the most current version of my application. I know how to open it in the app store, but my app is for a few different countries so do i need to specifiy what appstore they have to download the app from? Like my apps in london and china, do i need to customize the url to open up those app stores?

Answer (score 0):

The App Store page will be displayed based on the current user's phone locale.
Nothing to do on your side but using the generic link

Comment: Awesome but then another question comes to mind. Say the user lives in hong kong, but at the time of loading up the link for the application they are in the US. Which app store wil be loaded up? The US? I dont hink this will pose an issue if they download it from the US app store but id just like to know. We do a lot of apps that span a few countries

Comment: The store will not change if the users travels.

Comment: So the localization of the application is predetermined by the user then? possibly in settings? So then i have no control over what store is loaded up when they open the link?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The displayed language is based on the locale phone and - of course - the available translation on the App Store. The loaded store will be the one currently set up on the user phone. If the app you are trying to redirect to is not available in it a popup will prompt the user to change the App Store country